# This code is returning the error 'local variable 'name' referenced before assignment'.I am trying to keep a form and formset together

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to make a form and formset work together which are not related to each other.Any suggestions if there are easy solutions to this?

```
def resume(request):
    form=ResumeForm(request.POST)
    ExperienceFormSet=formset_factory(Experience)
    formset=ExperienceFormSet(request.POST,request.FILES) 
    print(form.is_valid)
    if request.method=='POST':
        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            name=request.POST.get('name')
            email=request.POST.get('email')
            phone=form.cleaned_data['phone']
            objective=request.POST.get('objective')
            branch=request.POST.get('branch')
            course=request.POST.get('course')
            course_total=course+' in '+branch
            department=request.POST.get('department')
            other_link=request.POST.get('other_link')
            for f in formset:
                cd=f.cleaned_data
                companyName=cd.get('companyName')
                print(companyName)
    else:
        form=ResumeForm()
        ExperienceFormSet=formset_factory(Experience)
        formset=ExperienceFormSet() 

    return render(request,'resume.html',{'name':name,'email':email,'phone':phone,'objective':objective,'course_total':course_total,'department':department,'other_link':other_link})
```

Comment: What if the request is not a POST or the form is not valid? Then `name` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

if `request.method` isn't 'POST', the variable `name` will never be created. Thus, when your function tries to return this part: `{'name':name` it won't find the variable `name` and it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

These two lines might cause the problem:

```
if request.method=='POST':
    if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
```

First if `request.method` is not a `POST` then the name variable will not be created thus name referenced before assignment error will occur. Same for second line of code too. You can solve this problem with like this:

```
if request_method=='POST':
        form_valid=form.is_valid()
        formset_valid=formset.is_valid()
        if form_valid and formset_valid:
            # ...
# ... 
if request_method=="POST" and form_valid and formset_valid:
        return render(request,'resume.html',{'name':name,'email':email,'phone':phone,'objective':objective,'course_total':course_total,'department':department,'other_link':other_link})
else:
   # Something is not valid you need to handle this.
```

Comment: request_valid=request.method()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
[16/Oct/2019 10:40:38] "POST /resume_final/ HTTP/1.1" 500 73905

Comment: After submitting the form,the following error is appearing:
'str' object is not callable

Comment: I could not understand what change you made.It is still not working.Sorry

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few things wrong with your view: you create a bound form right from the start (uselessly when it's a GET request), you use the raw `request.POST` data instead of the sanitized ones from the form's `cleaned_data`, and - the issue you mention - you try to inconditionnally use variables that are only conditionnally defined.

The proper canonical function-based-view template for form submissions is:

```
def myview(request):
   # if you have variables that you want to always
   # be in the context, the safest way is to define 
   # them right from the start (with a dummy value):

   name = None

   # now FIRST test the request method:
   if request.method == "POST":
       # and ONLY then build a bound form:
       form = MyForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           # use sanitized data, not raw POST data:
           name = form.cleaned_data["name"]

   else:
      # build an unbound form
      form = MyForm()

   # here you know that both variables have been defined whatever
   return render(request, "mytemplate.html", {"form": form, "name": name}
```

Comment: How to make a form and formset which are not related to each other submit with a single submit button and make the 'POST' data display in another webpage?Please help!